# WCF: The InnerException message was 'Maximum number of items that can be > serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2010, config, wcf-binding, timer-jobs

I know many have posted the solutions about this, I have tried all of solutions that were posted on the internet but those didn't work for me. In this scenario, I want to **consume WCF service from a SharePoint timer job.**

I am constantly getting the issue stated below:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter 
>   `http://test/MyEntry/2010/03:GetResult`. The InnerException message
>   was 'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in
>   an object graph is '65536'. Change the object graph or increase the
>   MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota. '. Please see InnerException for more
>   details.

My Server side web.config for SVC is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IVerksamhetService_server" closeTimeout="10:10:00"
            openTimeout="10:10:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:10:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false" >
                 <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />                  
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
      <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="SomeService.DeluxeEntryBehavior" name="SomeService.DeluxeEntry">
          <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SomeService.IVerksamhetService" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IVerksamhetService_server" >
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost"/>
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
      </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="SomeService.DeluxeEntryBehavior">
                      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />          
                      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

My client side config (I added this configuration in `OWSTIMER.EXE.CONFIG` file)

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IVerksamhetService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                  <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="64" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />                  
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceViewEventBehavior">
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>    
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://testserver.ivodmz.za/TestService/MyWCF.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IVerksamhetService"
                contract="IVerksamhetService" behaviorConfiguration= "ServiceViewEventBehavior" name="WSHttpBinding_IVerksamhetService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>       
    </system.serviceModel>
```

**Update:**

**I have WCF endpoint setting the limit to 65536 but how can make the endpoint to ignore dll behavior and use what is specified in the XML configuration** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add behavior to congig and aad it to service

```
<serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="DefaultBehavior" MaxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647">
         <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: It's already added at Client and Server, so what's wrong with my Configs (stated in my question)

Comment: Yes, there was a override behavior in the code. How can I undo this? Keeping in mind I can't re-build the dll. How can ask Web service to take XML configuration.

Comment: you can't change it, dll replaces config and start wcf, you can't override it, but may be reflection can help...